# CODESYS 3.5.12, added AC_ModuleBase and AC_Persistance without meaning too How to remove?

Tags: libraries, codesys

I added the AC_ModuleBase and AC_Persistance module into codesys 3.5.12, ive tryed removing them via the library manager but i keep getting the following error even after removing them:

```
            ------ Build started: Application: Device.Application -------
            typify code ...
```

**[ERROR]         Cortex_Firmware_V0_rev2840: Image format <.gif> is not supported by the target. (Visualization IP_Toplevel_Template from library ac_modulebase, 3.5.12.0 (3s - smart software solutions gmbh))**
Compile complete -- 1 errors, 0 warnings
Build complete -- 1 errors, 0 warnings : no download possible!

I tried reinstalling codesys but the problem lies with my project, I'm not entirely sure how the modules section works, even though i removed the libraries why would they still cause problems?

Codesys 3.5 doesn't seem to provide much in the way of looking for mentions of these libraries?